# Simpson's proof of the Gandy Kreisel Tait theorem in $\textbf{ATR}_0$

Tags: logic, descriptive-set-theory, reverse-math

I believe there is an error in Simpson's book "Subsystems of Second Order Arithmetic". Theorem VIII.6.4 states: $\textbf{ATR}_0$ proves that any $Y$ such that $Y_i=\{(n,i)\in y:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\not\leq_H X$ and if $\exists W\varphi(W,X)$ where $\varphi$ is a $\Sigma^1_1$ formula then $\exists W(\varphi(W,X)\wedge \forall i,j W_i\neq Y_j)$.

Proof: By Kleene normal form we have that $\varphi(W,X)$ is equivalent to $\exists f \forall n \theta(W[n],f[n],X)$. We define $\theta^*(\sigma,\tau, X)$ to be:
\begin{equation}
\exists W,f (W[|\sigma]=\sigma\wedge f[|\tau|]=\tau \wedge \forall n \theta(W[n],f[n],X)
\end{equation}
which informally states that $(\sigma,\tau)$ are an extendible element of the tree given by the Kleene normal form. By $f[n]$ we mean the sequence given by restriction of $f$ to $[0,n-1]$. We have that the following formulas can be expressed by a $\Sigma^1_1$ formula over $\Sigma^1_1$ axiom of choice: for every $X$ computable well order $\alpha$ the set $X^{(\alpha)}$ exists, $\forall i(Y_i\not\leq_H X)$, and $\exists W\varphi(W,X)$.

By a previous lemma one can construct a coded $\omega$ model of $\textbf{ACA}_0$ in which those propositions listed before hold. We have that $M$ satisfies $\theta(\emptyset,\emptyset,X)$ and we wish to show that if $ M \vDash \theta^* (\sigma,\tau,X)$
then for all $i,j\in \mathbb{N}$ there exists $\sigma'$ that is an extension of $\sigma$ and $M\vDash \theta^* (\sigma',\tau,X)\wedge (Y)_i[|\sigma'|]\neq (\sigma')_j$. If this does not hold then there are $i,j\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $m\in \mathbb{N}$ and $k\leq 1$ we have:
\begin{equation}
(Y)_i(m)=k\leftrightarrow M\vDash \exists \sigma'\supseteq\sigma (\theta^*(\sigma',\tau,X)\wedge (\sigma')_j(m)=k)
\end{equation}

Simpson then states that $M$ would then satisfy $(Y)_i$ being $\Delta^1_1$ and therefore $Y_i\leq_H X$. This however is not clear to me, what is clear to me is that $Y_i\leq_H X$ holds outside of $M$ since satisfiabiliy for coded $\omega$-models is $\Delta^1_1$ definable in $\textbf{ACA}_0$. It seems to me that $(Y)_i\leq_H X$ outside of $M$ is also sufficient to get a contradiction. This means that I do not need $M$ to also satisfy $\forall i((Y)_i\not\leq_H X)$ and that for every $\alpha$ the set $X^{(\alpha)}$ since I derive the contradiction outside of $M$ where these proposition already hold.

The proof after is straightforward. We construct recursively two increasing chains of sequence of $\sigma_n$ and $\tau_n$ such that $\theta^* (\sigma_n,\tau_n,X)$ and $n=(i,j) $ then $(Y)_i [|\sigma_n|] \neq (\sigma_n)_j$ . Setting $W=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\sigma_n$ gives us the wanted set which concludes the proof.

Is it necessary to show that $(Y)_i$ is $\Delta^1_1$ for the proof to work and is there a mistake in Simpson's proof?